# output to csv in a similar manner 'print' outputs to terminal?

Tags: ruby, csv

the logic included in my ruby code is a little difficult to translate into a csv output, is there a way to append each `value` in a similar manner that `print` works when outputting to the terminal?

cop_log is a hash of thousands of records

```
cop_log = { 'A1' => 'val1', 'B1' => 'val2', 'C1' => 'val3', 'D1' => 'val4, 'E1' => 'val5', 'F1' => 'val6', 'G1' => 'val7', 'H1' => 'val8', 'I1' => 'val9', 'J1' => 'val10, 'K1' => 'val11', 'A2' => 'val12', 'B2' => 'val13', 'C2' => 'val14', 'D2' => 'val15, 'E2' => 'val16', 'F2' => 'val17', 'G2' => 'val18', 'H2' => 'val19', 'I2' => 'val20', 'J2' => 'val21, 'K2' => 'val22'}

cop_log.each do |key, value|
  if key.include?('K')
    print "#{value}\n"
  elsif key.include?('A')
    print "#{job_number},#{pm_lookup[job_number]},#{value},"
  elsif key.include?('B') || key.include?('C') || key.include?('D') ||
        key.include?('E') || key.include?('F') || key.include?('G') ||
        key.include?('H') || key.include?('I') || key.include?('J')
    print "#{value},"
  end
end
```

currently outputs in the terminal like this, i want it to print to a csv in the same way:

```
val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9, val10, val11
val12, val13, val14, val15, val16, val17, val18, val19, val10, val21, val22
```

reading the documentation it looks like the common route is to do the following,

```
CSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
  csv << ["another", "row"]
  # ...
end
```

unfortunately the structure of my code is going to make that a little difficult....

Comment: As we're learning APIs we tend to paint ourselves into corners and attempt to get out of a situation by wanting to change the API rather than our code. It's better to go with the flow and use the API as it intends. You'll find your code will be more readable. As written, your code isn't idiomatic and could be rewritten more clearly. I'd consider this an opportunity to refactor. As for your "question", you didn't ask one. We can guess you want help but it'd help us and others if you'd more clearly state your goals.

Comment: What do your `key`s look like? Are they single-letters you're matching, or are you trying to find letters inside a string? Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We need minimal input data and the expected output.

Comment: thank you for your comments and answer, the keys are from a hash compiled out of an excel spreadsheet using the creek gem. an entire excel spreadsheet is inside my hash, the hash keys are each cell like A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C2 etc. my code is sorting out each row. its for working with a specific excel file template used at a specific corporation. I will rethink my approach. @theTinMan

Comment: This information needs to be entered into your question as if you'd specified it initially. Edit the question, add the information where you would have so it all makes sense. Don't use "Edit" or "Updated" tags as we can tell what was added when using SO's edit history.

Answer (score 1):

This is very confusing and, if cleaned up, would help make your code much more readable and maintainable:

```
if key.include?('K')
  print "#{value}\n"
elsif key.include?('A')
  print "#{job_number},#{pm_lookup[job_number]},#{value},"
elsif key.include?('B') || key.include?('C') || key.include?('D') ||
  key.include?('E') || key.include?('F') || key.include?('G') ||
  key.include?('H') || key.include?('I') || key.include?('J')
  print "#{value},"
end
```

What is `key`? A string of characters or a single character? If you're matching single characters you could do something like:

```
if key == 'K'
  print "#{value}\n"
elsif key == 'A'
  print "#{job_number},#{pm_lookup[job_number]},#{value},"
elsif ('B'.. 'J').include?(key)
elsif 
  print "#{value},"
end
```

and even convert:

```
elsif ('B'.. 'J').include?(key)
```

to:

```
elsif ('B'..'J') === key
```

If you're searching for a character match inside strings:

```
if key['K']
  print "#{value}\n"
elsif key['A']
  print "#{job_number},#{pm_lookup[job_number]},#{value},"
elsif key[/[B-J]/]
  print "#{value},"
end
```

At this point you're ready to tackle cleaning up the CSV output. I'd recommend starting over using one of [the basic examples](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-To+a+File) of CSV output in the class documentation. I'd also recommend carefully reading "[Comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)" so you're more familiar with the expectations of a CSV formatted file.

(Note: At this point the input sample hash was added to the question showing the actual format of the keys.)

I'll let you figure out how to incorporate CSV, but meditate on this:

```
cop_log = { 'A1' => 'val1', 'B1' => 'val2', 'C1' => 'val3', 'D1' => 'val4', 'E1' => 'val5', 'F1' => 'val6', 'G1' => 'val7', 'H1' => 'val8', 'I1' => 'val9', 'J1' => 'val10', 'K1' => 'val11', 'A2' => 'val12', 'B2' => 'val13', 'C2' => 'val14', 'D2' => 'val15', 'E2' => 'val16', 'F2' => 'val17', 'G2' => 'val18', 'H2' => 'val19', 'I2' => 'val20', 'J2' => 'val21', 'K2' => 'val22'}
cop_log.values.each_slice(11) do |slice|
  puts slice.join(',')
end

# >> val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7,val8,val9,val10,val11
# >> val12,val13,val14,val15,val16,val17,val18,val19,val20,val21,val22
```

You need to rely on the CSV class to create CSV files; The format isn't as simple as it seems.

---

Here's a first pass of how I'd write the code:

```
require 'csv'

cop_log = { 'A1' => 'val1', 'B1' => 'val2', 'C1' => 'val3', 'D1' => 'val4', 'E1' => 'val5', 'F1' => 'val6', 'G1' => 'val7', 'H1' => 'val8', 'I1' => 'val9', 'J1' => 'val10', 'K1' => 'val11', 'A2' => 'val12', 'B2' => 'val13', 'C2' => 'val14', 'D2' => 'val15', 'E2' => 'val16', 'F2' => 'val17', 'G2' => 'val18', 'H2' => 'val19', 'I2' => 'val20', 'J2' => 'val21', 'K2' => 'val22'}

job_number = 1
pm_lookup = [0, 1]

CSV.open('./foo.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  cop_log.group_by{ |k, v| k[1] }.values.each do |row|
    csv << [ job_number, pm_lookup[job_number], *row.map{ |k, v| v } ]
  end
end
```

After running, `foo.csv` contains:

```
1,1,val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7,val8,val9,val10,val11
1,1,val12,val13,val14,val15,val16,val17,val18,val19,val20,val21,val22
```

We don't know what your expected output is, since you didn't tell us, but you could work from that code and figure it out.

Here's a break-down of the preprocessing of the data:

```
cop_log.group_by{ |k, v| k[1] } # => {"1"=>[["A1", "val1"], ["B1", "val2"], ["C1", "val3"], ["D1", "val4"], ["E1", "val5"], ["F1", "val6"], ["G1", "val7"], ["H1", "val8"], ["I1", "val9"], ["J1", "val10"], ["K1", "val11"]], "2"=>[["A2", "val12"], ["B2", "val13"], ["C2", "val14"], ["D2", "val15"], ["E2", "val16"], ["F2", "val17"], ["G2", "val18"], ["H2", "val19"], ["I2", "val20"], ["J2", "val21"], ["K2", "val22"]]}
       .values # => [[["A1", "val1"], ["B1", "val2"], ["C1", "val3"], ["D1", "val4"], ["E1", "val5"], ["F1", "val6"], ["G1", "val7"], ["H1", "val8"], ["I1", "val9"], ["J1", "val10"], ["K1", "val11"]], [["A2", "val12"], ["B2", "val13"], ["C2", "val14"], ["D2", "val15"], ["E2", "val16"], ["F2", "val17"], ["G2", "val18"], ["H2", "val19"], ["I2", "val20"], ["J2", "val21"], ["K2", "val22"]]]
```

In the code above I'm making sure the input is in an expected order, in this case I'm grouping by single-digit rows. More robust code would use `\d+` instead of `1` and would also sort to force the appropriate order.

This is really important any time you're massaging data from one format into another for later reuse. While current Rubies guarantee that a hash will maintain its insertion order, it's not a good practice to assume since old versions of Ruby didn't do that, and other languages you port the code to might not maintain order. Instead always program defensively, making sure you're going to return consistent results. To what extent you do that is something you'll learn when you find out a previous attempt wasn't enough. Programming is fun that way.

Finally, any time your code feels awkward or isn't flowing it's time to back up and look at what you're doing.

Comment: unfortunately each key is a letter number pair, it comes directly out of an excel spreadsheet, A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C2 etc, thank you for the response though

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do this?

```
CSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
    cop_log.each do |key, value|
        if key.include?('A')
            csv << [ job_number, pm_lookup[job_number], value ]
        elsif key.include?('K') || key.include?('B') || key.include?('C') || key.include?('D') ||
            key.include?('E') || key.include?('F') || key.include?('G') ||
            key.include?('H') || key.include?('I') || key.include?('J')
            csv << [ value ]
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def write_csv(cop_log, io = $stdout)
  cop_log.each do |key, value|
    if key.include?('K')
      io.print "#{value}\n"
    elsif key.include?('A')
      io.print "#{job_number},#{pm_lookup[job_number]},#{value},"
    elsif key.include?('B') || key.include?('C') || key.include?('D') ||
          key.include?('E') || key.include?('F') || key.include?('G') ||
          key.include?('H') || key.include?('I') || key.include?('J')
      io.print "#{value},"
    end
  end
end
```

Then

```
File.open('path/to/file.csv', 'w') do |f|
  write_csv(cop_log, f)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

re fector the code

```
    CSV.open("test.csv", "ab") do |csv|
      b = {}
      check_num = 0
      cop_log.each do |key, value|
        num = key.gsub(/[^\d]/, '').to_i
        next if num < 8 ||
                key.include?('L') || key.include?('M') || key.include?('N') ||
                key.include?('O') || key.include?('P') || key.include?('Q') ||
                key.include?('R') || key.include?('S') || key.include?('T') ||
                key.include?('U') || key.include?('V')
        a = { key => value }
        b.merge!(a)
      end # end of each loop
      i = 8
      while ((b.length / 9) - 7) > i do
        csv << [ job_number, pm_lookup[job_number], b["A#{i}"], b["B#{i}"],
                b["C#{i}"], b["D#{i}"], b["E#{i}"], b["F#{i}"], b["G#{i}"],
                b["H#{i}"], b["I#{i}"], b["J#{i}"], b["K#{i}"] ]
        i += 1
      end
    end # end of CSV.open
```